# how to get result in mysql IN and NOT IN with order by array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query and i want to show the result in order by field

```
$sqlse .= "SELECT ".$tableColumn. " FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$where." AND ".$table2.".account_id IN (353,176,9) OR NOT IN".$table2.".account_id IN (353,176,9)  ORDER BY FIELD(account_id,353,176,9)";
```

I want to show the results in order

```
account_id             Name

353                    sandy
176                    Abhi
9                      jill
42                     prahsnt
435                    jack
```

but it show the result in order

```
42                     prashant
435                    jack
353                    sandy
176                    abhi
9                      jill
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because it returns 0 if it can't find the value in the list you pass to the `FIELD` funcion

try this:

```
... ORDER BY FIELD(account_id, 9 , 176, 353) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT ".$tableColumn. " FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$where." AND 
 ".$table2.".account_id IN (353,176,9)".
"UNION ALL".
"SELECT ".$tableColumn. " FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$where." AND 
 ".$table2.".account_id NOT IN (353,176,9)";
```